# Use a custom control in DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a generic custom control which contains a textbox and a button. Other custom controls inherit from this generic one and specify a concrete type, eg:

```
public class CustomerType
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

The generic control has a `Value` property which depends on the Type parameter and a `Text` property, which, depending on the type, might display `CustomerType.Description` or `ProductType.Name`.

These controls are used for search (eg. customer types, product types, etc).

These controls work fine when placed on normal forms. Now I need to place such controls inside DataGridView columns, so I tried to follow this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Currently, the 2 derived classes look like this:

```
public class CustomerTypeColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public CustomerTypeColumn()
        : base(new CustomerTypeCell()) 
    { }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CustomerTypeCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Should be CustomerTypeCell.");
            }

            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomerTypeCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public CustomerTypeCell() 
        : base() 
    { }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomerType);
        }
    }
}
```

But the column is still displaying a textbox instead of my custom control. What am I missing here? Furthermore, How and where am I going to save the `Value` property for the cell in grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't overridden the `EditType`of `CustomerTypeCell`. Thatswhy its still showing the default editing control of `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` which is a `TextBox`.

You have to create custom editing control just like in the MSDN link you have referenced or implement the `IDataGridViewEditingControl` control in your custom control. Return the type of the custom editing control in the `EditType`.

```
public class CustomerTypeCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public CustomerTypeCell() 
        : base() 
    { }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomerType);
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {                 
            return typeof(CustomEditingControl);
        }
    }       
}
```

The cell has already a value property. Store the control's value property in it.